# scala assigning string and array of values

Tags: string, scala

I'm trying to assign a string followed by an array of scores.

I defined some categories

```
case class CategoryScore(    //Define Category Score class
val food: Int,
val tech: Int,
val service: Int,
val fashion: Int)
```

and mapped them to some keys so that a String such as the name of a product would be followed by the case class of scores.

```
var keywordscores:Map[String, CategoryScore] = Map()    //keyword scores

keywordscores += ("amazon",CategoryScore(1,9,1,4))     //Tried to add score for a string, does not work
```

am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> keywordscores += ("amazon" -> CategoryScore(1,9,1,4))
```

or (note the extra parenthesis)

```
scala> keywordscores += (("amazon", CategoryScore(1,9,1,4)))
```

The reason for that is that `+` is defined as `+(kvs: (A, B)*): Map[A, B]`, meaning it can take any number of `(key,value)` pairs, leading to `+= (k,v)` being ambiguous.

The `a -> b` notation removes this ambiguity (and it's much nicer to read).

Answer (score 0):

Maps are added like

```
keywordscores += ("amazon" -> CategoryScore(1,9,1,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

With a mutable `Map` you can also update/insert entries as follows,

```
val keywordscores:collection.mutable.Map[String, CategoryScore] = Map()

keywordscores("amazon") = CategoryScore(1,9,1,4))
```

Here a new entry with key `"amazon"` is inserted; a subsequent call with the same key will update the value.